# Python on Unix :: Value of os.EX_NOTFOUND

Tags: python, macos

The documentation for the Python `os` module provides a set of exit statuses available on Unix.

macOS is Unix.

However, `os.EX_NOTFOUND` returns

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'EX_NOTFOUND'
```

What's going on here? More specifically, what should be the value of this constant? My guess is that it should be `79` but I don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the top of the exit codes section, right above [os.EX_OK](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.EX_OK) it says:

> Some of these may not be available on all Unix platforms, since there
>   is some variation. These constants are defined where they are defined
>   by the underlying platform.

So the MacOS platform does not implement it. Neither does Linux as it seems. I found it on a Solaris and there it has the expected value of 79